# Inserting UTF-8 into MySQL gives gibberish

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following when I do this command in MYSQL Browser

```
'character_set_client', 'utf8'
'character_set_connection', 'utf8'
'character_set_database', 'utf8'
'character_set_filesystem', 'binary'
'character_set_results', 'utf8'
'character_set_server', 'utf8'
'character_set_system', 'utf8'
'character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/'
```

But when I call something like this to my servlet it saves as gibberish

```
http://something.com/TestServlet/test?cmd=1&id=999&content=%E6%90%9C%E7%8B%97%E6%90%9C
```

The characters at the end are chinese characters.

I have this code in my servlet to get the content as UTF8

```
OutputStream ostream = response.getOutputStream();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(ostream, true, "UTF8");

String content = request.getParameter("content");
```

Then I call an insert on the database something like db.insert(content); This is just pseudo of course.

I even added `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to my connection string but to no avail.

搜狗搜 is displayed as æçæ in mysql query browser

Comment: We'll need to know how the servlet uses what you provide it with... Maybe what messes it up is your application server and not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the tomcat side had to add a URI-Encoding=UTF-8 to the connection in the server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:
try to send initial command on DB connection:  SET NAMES 'utf8'

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL configuration and ensure that your encoding is defined correctly. Add these lines to the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf). These settings should work:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
```

Comment: Have you restarted mysqld after modifying my.cnf?

Comment: Make also sure that the DDL you use to create the database and the tables have DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8.

Comment: Yeah this is the in the last line of the create statement ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); // Simpler

request.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```